# finding 1st red (255,0,0) pixel position? using matlab

Tags: matlab

I trying to find first red colour's pixel position in the image using matlab.

what I do

```
I = imread('test.jpg');

row = size(I,1);
col = size(I,2);

for rr = 1:row
    for cc = 1:col
        if [rr cc :] = [ 255 0 0 ]
            flag =1;
            break;
        end
     end
end
```

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is problematic.
First, there is a fundamental difference between `=` operator and `==` operator (not only in matlab). While the first (`=`) is an **assignment operator, the second (`==`) is a boolean test - which is what you want.
Second, you need to compare the image values at location `rr,cc` and not the locations themselves.

```
if squeeze( I(rr,cc,:) ) == [255;0;0]
```

Is more likely to do what you expect.

While we are at it, it is a better practice to vectorize matlab statements. Something like:

```
[rr cc] = find( I(:,:,1) == 255 & I(:,:,2) == 0 & I(:,:,3) == 0 , 1, 'first' );
```

**EDIT:** Some more details on the vectorized method:
The expression

```
 I(:,:,1) == 255 & I(:,:,2) == 0 & I(:,:,3) == 3
```

Creates a 2D boolean matrix, the same size as `I` (apart from the third dimension) with `true` for each red pixel and `false` otherwise.
The [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) returns the indices of the `true` entries of the boolean expression.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the above as how to retrieve the first pixel position of red colour.